# Under what conditions, the converse of the claim "continuous functions take limits to limits" is also true?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a function, and a set $A \subset X$ where $A = \{x_\lambda | \lambda \in \Lambda\}$ where $\Lambda$ is a directed set.
Suppose that x is a limit point of $A$ in the sense that for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists an $\lambda_0 \in \Lambda$ such that for every $ \lambda > \lambda_0 $, we have $x_\lambda \in U$.

My question is, **when does this imply that $f$ is continuous in $x$?**
Of course, the converse claim is true and mentioned a lot: if f is continuous, then it takes limit points to limit points.
I am tring to figure out in what conditions the stated above claim is also true.

Thank you!
Shir

Answer (score 2):

If **every** net in $X$ converging to $x$ is taken by $f$ to a net in $Y$ converging to $f(x)$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Suppose that $f$ is not continuous at $x$. Let $y=f(x)$, and let $U$ be an open nbhd of $y$ such that for each nbhd $N$ of $x$, $f[N]\nsubseteq U$. Let $\mathscr{N}$ be the set of open nbhds of $x$, and for each $N\in\mathscr{N}$ let $x_N\in N$ be such that $f(x_N)\notin U$. Then $\langle\mathscr{N},\supseteq\rangle$ is a directed set, and $\langle x_N:N\in\mathscr{N}\rangle$ is a net in $X$ converging to $x$, but $\langle f(x_N):N\in\mathscr{N}\rangle$ does not converge to $f(x)$ in $Y$.

Comment: In other words, with a sufficiently strong and general concept of convergence, the answer is Yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Shir: You’re welcome!